# WPF tab items header name

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, tabs

I have one tab control and i insert dynamically tabs. I want to get the header names of the tab items in order to check for duplicates. How can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var headers = tabControl.Items.Cast<TabItem>().Select(x => x.Header);
```

Comment: This is just a single line of code with no commentary which is usually a target for flagging as not an answer. You could possibly extend your answer to show how to check for duplicates in the `headers` result  using LINQ.

Comment: @slugster Thanks for the comment. However, I'll leave the duplicates checking as an exercise for the OP, since I believe SO should not serve as "give me teh codez" base. I usually try to add comments to my answers, but in this case, I think the code speaks for itself.